# Amazon S3 Accesing website from bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

> Hi, I have made a bucket on Amazon S3 and uploaded my website in bucket but the problem is my website pages are getting downloaded when i open any page suppose Default.aspx . I want to access the page and not download it.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 service doesn't hosts dynamic websites(ASP.net), it's a storage service and can only hosts static websites(HTML), but you can use amazon EC2 service witch give you a complete control.

Answer (score 0):

have you set content type for the aspx pages. Check the Content-Type ? 
try : 
text/html; charset=utf-8